# Angular HTTP client how to know when a chunked download request finished?

Tags: javascript, angular, express

I am using angular [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) to download an `arraybuffer`, the server is sending the data with the following headers:

**To prevent confusion, the download route basically downloads a chunk file saved in the cloud, but the download itself sends the chunk in chunks*

That's the backend part written in NestJS which is a framework on top of Express:

```
@Get(`chunk/:fileKey/:startBytes/:endBytes`)
public async download(@Req() req, @Res() res,
                      @Param('fileKey') fileKey: string,
                      @Param('startBytes') startBytes: number,
                      @Param('endBytes') endBytes: number) {

    res.setHeader("content-type", "application/octet-stream");
    res.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private");
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");

    const downloadRequest: DownloadChunkDto = {
        fileKey,
        startBytes,
        endBytes
    };

    const stream = await this.fileTransferProvider.getChunkDownload(req.sessionObject.id, downloadRequest);
    stream.pipe(res);
}
```

I load the file using my provider that provides that functionality and passes the stream to the response of express.

And I download it with this:

```
this.http.request(httpRequest).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('chunk received!', data);
});
```

I receive the chunks, but I cannot know when the process has finished. Tried using `finalize` as pipe, and it's called every time a chunk is sent.

In the network tab, I see a separated request for each chunk sent as well, so I am not really sure if this is possible without making the server tell the client when the stream has ended

Answer (score 0):

There are more phases inside your `observable` when you `subscribe` to it, maybe this could help:

```js
this.http.request(httpRequest).subscribe({
       next(chunck) { console.log('got chunck' + ); },
       error(err) { console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err); },
       complete() { console.log('done'); }
});
```

Or you could use `concatMap` and wait for all chunks to be sent and then, `subscribe` to the final result.

```js
this.http.request(httpRequest)
  .pipe(
    concatMap((data) => of(data))
  )
  .subscribe((response) => console.log('response', response);
```

[concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap)

[Observables Rxjs](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable)

Comment: Shouldn't concatMap return something?

Comment: @BenBeri, you are right, I edited my answer